# Omitting the word "for"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Is there a difference in meaning between these two?

1. Services must be paid.
2. Services must be paid for.

Comment: Please read these links http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pay+for http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pay

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The word *for* shifts the indirect object* of *paid* somewhere else.

Consider

> - I must be paid
> - I must be paid for

In the first, I receive the money. In the second, someone else receives it in order to cover my cost.

"Services must be paid" means that the services receive the money. It's *grammatical,* as far as it goes, but it doesn't make a lot of sense.

"Services must be paid for" means that someone (person A) has to pay someone (person B) for the services.

There is a substantial difference between the two.

---

It may be doubtful whether the direct oject of *pay* is the recipient of the money or the money itself (which often doesn't need to be mentioned explicitly). But the use of *for* diverts the money elsewhere.

Comment: About "services receive the money": What about paying the bill, or paying your debt to society?

Comment: What about them? If you have another question, please ask it.

Comment: Well, wouldn't your answer imply that "The bill must be paid" means that the bill receives the money? Isn't that false? Isn't your answer therefore false?

Comment: No, because idioms and set phrases defy rationalisation.